# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: entity-framework-core

I got this error below. I am using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore (.NET 7.0).

```
DatabaseError : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String scope)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginDbTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at TEST.API.Middlewares.TransactionMiddleware.DbTransactionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, DatabaseContext dbContext) in /src/TEST.API/Middlewares/TransactionMiddleware.cs:line 142
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String scope)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginDbTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at TEST.API.Middlewares.TransactionMiddleware.DbTransactionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, DatabaseContext dbContext) in /src/TEST.API/Middlewares/TransactionMiddleware.cs:line 142
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I have an TransactionMiddleware like below

```
using TEST.API.Exceptions;
using TEST.API.PipelineBehaviors.PreProcessor;
using TEST.Cores.Constants;
using TEST.Cores.EFContext;
using TEST.Cores.Logs;
using TEST.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using static CRM.API.Middlewares.TransactionMiddleware;

namespace TEST.API.Middlewares
{
    public class TransactionMiddleware
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
        public class ManualTransactionAttribute : Attribute
        {
        }

        public class DbTransactionMiddleware
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

            public DbTransactionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                _next = next;
            }

            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, DatabaseContext dbContext)
            {
                var request = httpContext.Request;
                // For HTTP GET opening transaction is not required
                if (request.Method.Equals("GET", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    await _next(httpContext);
                    return;
                }

                var requestContent = "";
                var rUserID = "";
                var serviceID = "";

                //// If action is not decorated with ManualTransactionAttribute then skip opening transaction
                var endpoint = httpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
                var attribute = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ManualTransactionAttribute>();
                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (request.Method == HttpMethods.Post && request.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            request.EnableBuffering();
                            var bodyStream = new StreamReader(request.Body);
                            bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            requestContent = await bodyStream.ReadToEndAsync();
                            request.Body.Position = 0;  //rewinding the stream to 0


                            ILogger logger = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RequestLogger>>();
                            Log.Info(logger, requestContent);
                        }

                        await _next(httpContext);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex is FastEndpoints.ValidationFailureException)
                        {
                        }
                        else if (ex is BusinessException)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        throw;

                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }


                try
                {
                    using (var transaction = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
                    {
                        if (request.Method == HttpMethods.Post && request.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            request.EnableBuffering();
                            var bodyStream = new StreamReader(request.Body);
                            bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            requestContent = await bodyStream.ReadToEndAsync();
                            request.Body.Position = 0;  //rewinding the stream to 0


                            ILogger logger = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<RequestLogger>>();
                            Log.Info(logger, requestContent);
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            await _next(httpContext);
                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
                            {
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is FastEndpoints.ValidationFailureException)
                    {
                    }
                    else if (ex is BusinessException)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    throw;

                }
                finally

                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseDbTransaction(this WebApplication app)
            => app.UseMiddleware<DbTransactionMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

And the setup for DatabaseContext

```
internal static async void AddDbContexts(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, string contextConnectionString)
        {
            if (StringUtils.IsNullOrEmpty(contextConnectionString))
            {
                contextConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? "";
            }
            services.AddDbContextPool<DatabaseContext>(x => x.UseMySQL(contextConnectionString, o =>
                {
                    o.CommandTimeout(900);
                })
                .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
        }
```

From my understand, for each request, we will have an DatabaseContext and that DbContext will have its own connection.
But why when I tried to BeginTransaction in the TransactionMiddleWare. It turned to this error.

Can someone explain me about this.
Thank you for your support